# $cookies doesn't work in angularjs v1.3.2 for IE 11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, cookies

I have a directive to control a cookie for privacy policy:

```
// Cookies policy directive
app.directive('cookiesPolicy', function ($cookies, $document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', 
    templateUrl: 'layouts/cookies-policy.html',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        var _consent = $cookies['cookie-name'];

        $scope.consent = function (consent) {
            if (consent === undefined) {
                return _consent;
            } else if (consent) {
                $cookies['cookie-name'] = true;
               _consent = true;
            }
        }; 
    } 
  }
});
```

The fact is it works OK in Chrome and FF but not in IE11... The cookie is not being saved.

The version of angularjs is v1.3.2. Is there a fix for this version?

Thanks